# How to combine deferred and forward rendering together?

Tags: vulkan

i am trying to use deferred and forward rendering together. i have working code from opengl tutorial and i tried this to adapt to vulkan with same way.

this opengl way :

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, gBuffer_FrameBuffer);
//draw gBuffer

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, main_FrameBuffer);
//draw deferred

glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, gBuffer_FrameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, main_FrameBuffer); // write to default framebuffer
glBlitFramebuffer(0,0,SCR_WIDTH,SCR_HEIGHT,0,0,SCR_WIDTH,SCR_HEIGHT,GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT,GL_NEAREST);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, main_FrameBuffer);
//draw forward
```

in vulkan i set main_FrameBuffer renderpass like this for manuel clear

```
colorAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
depthAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
```

and tried:

```
vkBeginCommandBuffer()

vkCmdBeginRenderPass()//with gBuffer_FrameBuffer
//draw gBuffer
vkCmdEndRenderPass()

vkCmdBeginRenderPass()//main_FrameBuffer
vkCmdClearAttachments()// clear manuel
//draw deferred
vkCmdEndRenderPass()

vkCmdPipelineBarrier//src : gBuffer_FrameBuffer depth image
vkCmdPipelineBarrier//dst : main_FrameBuffer depth image
vkCmdBlitImage//copy gBuffer_FrameBuffer depth image to main_FrameBuffer depth image
vkCmdPipelineBarrier//src : gBuffer_FrameBuffer depth image
vkCmdPipelineBarrier//dst : main_FrameBuffer depth image

vkCmdBeginRenderPass()//main_FrameBuffer here i didn't clear manuel but i am taking black screen
//draw forward
vkCmdEndRenderPass()


vkEndCommandBuffer()
```

Comment: The "gbuffer" contains material properties like positions, normals, texture coordinates, etc. What does the "main" framebuffer contain such that it's reasonable to copy such data onto it? Also, what's the point of the "deferred" render to the main framebuffer if you're going to immediately overwrite it? What *exactly* are you doing here?

Comment: main framebuffer is swapchain framebuffer. I am not overwrite it. i am trying to copy depth image from gBuffer to main. if i could it , i can draw forward with depth testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> vkCmdPipelineBarrier//src : gBuffer_FrameBuffer depth ima/ge
> vkCmdPipelineBarrier//dst : main_FrameBuffer depth image/
> ```

OpenGL is not Vulkan.

In OpenGL, you effectively had 2 depth images. Your gbuffer FBO had a depth image, and the default framebuffer had a depth image. This was necessary because you cannot attach your gbuffer's depth image to the default framebuffer; you were forced to use the default framebuffer's depth image.

Vulkan *has no default framebuffer*. A swapchain image is not a framebuffer; it's just an image. Specifically, a *color* image. If you want to render to a swapchain image with depth testing, it is you who must provide a depth image.

Which can be the same one you used for your deferred rendering.

In fact, there is absolutely no reason to have more than one render pass in your system. You just need to have multiple subpasses.

The render pass contains several image attachments: whatever color attachments you need for the gbuffers, a depth attachment, and the swapchain image you're rendering to. Subpass 0 renders to the gbuffer attachments and depth attachment. Subpass 1 reads from the gbuffer&depth attachments as input attachments, and writes to the swapchain image. Subpass 2 writes to the swapchain image and depth attachment.

There is no need to copy anything in Vulkan here.